# How to install tensorflow 2.x with latest cuda version on ubuntu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I almost quit tensorflow because i did go some problem to get cuda install properly for tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to :
go to; https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html
choosethe right version of ubuntu then follow the guide.

Then run the following commande after  completing the guide installation
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit